# How to store text box value in hidden field

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to store text box value in hidden field. And need populate hidden value on  button click but the problem is Both button and text box are inside ASPxGridView.

ASPxGridView is hierarchical grid view i.e. (DetailRow)

**Code**

**Storing value into Hidden field**

```
 function YourJavaScriptFunction() {
           <%--$("#<%= hdn.ClientID %>").val($('<%# ((ASPxGridView)Container).FindControl("txtCustCode").ClientID %>').val());--%>
            $("#hdn").val($("txtCustCode").val());
        }
```

**HiddenField**

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**GridView**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid"
    KeyFieldName="LocationCode" Width="100%" OnDataBinding="dgDepots_DataBinding"
    OnRowDeleting="dgDepots_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgDepots_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="dgDepots_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="LocationCode" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="LocationCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="LocationName"
            VisibleIndex="0">
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="CostCenterCode" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="CostCenterCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="CostCenterName"
            VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="GLCode" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="GLAccountCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="GLAccountName"
            VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
    </Columns>
  <Templates>
        <DetailRow>
            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CustomerCode"
                OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect" OnDataBinding="dgCustomers_DataBinding"
                Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
                OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustomerCode" VisibleIndex="0">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustCode" runat="server" Width="50px" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction();" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PriceGroupCode" VisibleIndex="1">
                        <EditFormSettings Visible="True" />
                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ChannelCode" VisibleIndex="2">
                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="SubChannelCode" VisibleIndex="3">
                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="4">
                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                </Columns>
```

**CodeBehind on button click**

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var ss = hdn.Value;  **//Showing Null**
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AYOg.png)
Where i m doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi you have miss `#` near `$("txtCustCode")..` .

Comment: @Swati I change as you suggested $("#txtCustCode") But no changes

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done!

But,

$("txtCustCode") should've a '#' in it's id and you missed this thing...

Like this,

```
$("#hdn").val($("#txtCustCode").val());
```

If the above method doesn't work, Try the below code,

```
var hiddenField = document.getElementById("<%=hdn.ClientID%>");
var textFieldValue = document.getElementById("<%=txtCustCode.ClientID%>");

hiddenField.setAttribute("itemid",textFieldValue.value);
```

and get the value in code behind like this,

```
string itemId = hiddenField.Attributes["itemid"];
```

Good Luck...

Comment: I change my code as you suggested But still values is null

Comment: I think text box is inside grid view thatsy its unable to find textbox ID may be i am not sure but ..

Comment: While debugging its heating my function but not able to retrive value from text box

Comment: The value will not be saved in the hidden field when you press the button because the postback will happen when you click the button.

Comment: If you want to get the value from the hidden field you've to set the textbox value in an attribute of the hidden field or something instead of storing in hidden field value. For example you can set the value in "itemid" attribute of the hidden field and get the value in code behind...

Comment: Please check my Updated code. I am getting error on txtCustCode it just because its inside grid view how can i access this text box i don't understand please help me

Comment: Try this line from your old code,           $('<%#ASPxGridView)Container).FindControl("txtCustCode").ClientID %>'

Comment: I've changed the code. First declare the textbox id and get the value on the setAttribute line. Refer the answer

Comment: Now i can able to get data from Text box insted of passing Just Text box ID i just pass complete ID like $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgDepots_dxdt0_dgCustomers_0_DXEFL_0_editnew_0_0_txtCustCode").val();

Answer (score 0):

I just pass Complete ID of that text box inspect on browser in Element Tab search particular text box copy The from there and then paste same

```
"$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgDepots_dxdt0_dgCustomers_0_DXEFL_0_editnew_0_0_txtCustCode").val();"
```

And i can able to get value

Thanks all for your help